# How to enable Firebase App Check without Google Play Developer Account?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-app-check, google-play-integrity-api

Safety Net allowed App Check for apps that were not distributed through Google Play. Now that Safety Net is being removed, what is the alternative of using App Check for apps that are not distributed through Google Play as the alternative provided by Firebase (Play Integrity) allows App Check for only the apps that are distributed through Google Play?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [reCaptcha Enterprise](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/instrument-android-apps) for the attestation and then use the token generated by that as a [custom provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/custom-provider). There may be alternative attestation providers available, but that is the method I think flutter uses for mfa attestation in their Firebase UI package on Android.

Comment: Is there any way to use Play Integrity API for apps that are not distributed through Google Play?

Comment: Yes, you can write a custom provider to use the Google Play Integrity API.

Comment: Can you kindly mention a link where we can find a proper sample code to implement the Play Integrity API as custom provider?